# Neural Networks in R - Dynamic Training set

Tags: r, optimization, neural-network, training-data

I am currently building a neural network with R and NeurnalNet package ( http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/index.html ).

My training set is given by old data and everyday I want to add some data to this training set and updating the weights in my neural network without creating a new one. Do you think that is feasible?

I am facing slowness issue thats why I want to do the following thing:
1) add data to my training set
2) Updating the weights of my old neural network without launching the training step on the old data.

Is this method right according to you?

Thanks,

Alfam

Comment: You'll likely want an [online learning method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) which I don't believe neural networks are. Also, it's not super common to find implementations of online learning algorithms in R since that's not generally how one analyzes data in R.